# C++ standard template library vector question

Tags: c++, vector, standard-library

Can someone explain in English what is going on here?

```
std::vector<Cat*> cats; //I get that cats is a vector of Cat objects

if (std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris) == cats.end()) {
   cats.push_back(morris);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mlimber has already given one explanation.

I'd explain it a bit differently. In plain English, it's a way of taking something really simple:

```
 std::set<Cat> cats;

 cats.insert(morris);
```

and making it slower (linear instead of logarithmic) and considerably harder to read or understand.

Edit: In fairness, I suppose I should add that there *are* a few reasons you *might* want to do something like this. For example, if you really need to know the order in which `Cat`s were added to the collection, preserving the original order might make some sense. Likewise, if you're *usually* using the collection in a way that benefits from them being contiguous in memory, and only *rarely* adding a new item, it might make more sense to store the data in a `vector` than an `set`.

A `set`, however, is designed to do *exactly* what's being done here, so a `set` is the obvious choice (absent compelling reasons to use a `vector` that just aren't visible in what you've shown).

Comment: +1 Shame on me for never using std::set - I will now, thank you for pointing this out (should it not be std::set<Cat*>, though?)

Comment: so inserting into a set will check to make sure if it's not there already?

Comment: @sol: Yes. `set::insert(t)`: "inserts t if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of t." In the case of `set`, the key is the object.

Answer (score 2):

It adds an item called `morris` to the vector `cats` IF the vector doesn't already has it!

The `std::find` is used to check if the item `morris` is in the vector `cats` or not. It doesn't has, `std::find` returned value would be equal to `cats.end()`. After this, everything else is pretty much straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code is correct (like the type and initialization of morris and using pointers for your comparison), the point is to see if morris is in the collection of cats, and if not, to add him to it.

Answer (score 1):

cats is a vector of pointers to Cat objects, not a vector of Cat objects.

This searches the full range of cats(cats.begin() through cats.end()) for an object(pointer to cat) that is equal to morris

`std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris)`

The return value is an iterator into the vector pointing to the object if it was found, and it returns the end iterator(cats.end()) if it was not found.  With that in mind, this:

`if (std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris) == cats.end())`

is a test to see if cats contains that object(morris).  And if it doesn't, then it executes this:

`cats.push_back(morris);`

which puts the object(morris), into the vector.

Answer (score 1):

First be carefull : your comment is wrong. cats isn't a vector of Cat objects, but a vector of POINTERS to cat objects.

Now, the statement :

std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris)

implies you have a Cat* somewhere called morris. This statement is going to search the vector, between the two provided iterators (i.e : cats.begin() and cats.end() )  for a pointer to Cat, equall to morris (same address). If none is found, std::find returns the second iterator, so, in your case "cats.end()"

Therefore "if (std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris) == cats.end()) {  cats.push_back(morris); }" means, in plain english "if morris isn't already in the cats vector, put it at the end"

I'll have a hard time being more specific if we don't know what's bothering you exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Cat*> cats; //I get that cats is a vector of Cat objects
```

You get that wrong. `cats` is a `std::vector` of pointers to the class `Cat`. There's a difference: `Cat`s reside on the stack, are created by doing

```
Cat morris;
```

and do not have to be deleted. Pointers as in your example, are created by

```
Cat* morris = new Cat();
```

and have to be deleted once you're done with it before you throw away the pointer:

```
delete morris;
```

I will now add a little code to your example:

```
Cat* morris = new Cat();

if (std::find(cats.begin(), cats.end(), morris) == cats.end()) {
   cats.push_back(morris);
}
```

This creates a dynamically allocated object `morris` of type `Cat` on the heap. Then, `std::find` is used to search the vector `cats` for the newly created object, which will always fail in this code fragment. If `std::find` fails, it returns an iterator to the element one past the last element in the container (which is exactly what `std::vector::end()` returns). So if `morris` is not found, the code will create a new element at the back of the vector and add `morris` to it.